# Deleting every n-many columns in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that I'd like to reduce by keeping every 36 columns and removing every 18 columns between; ie: for every 36 columns the next 18 are to be removed and then repeated from those next 36 until the end of the DataFrame.

The DataFrame is (11, 432) but a working example for every 5 columns (instead of 36) remove 2 (instead of 18) would look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0':[1, 12, 13, 15, 10, 5, 6, 10, 21, 2, 3, 14, 8, 22, 12], '1':[11, 2, 43, 6, 12, 5, 6, 10, 22, 2, 3, 14, 4, 1, 5]}).T

df_reduced_example

     0    1    2    3    4    7    8    9   10   11   14
0    1    12   13   15   10   10   21   2   3    14   12
1    11   2    43   6    12   10   22   2   3    14   5
```

So far I can only seem to get each starting point for every 37th column:

```
df_reduced = df[df.columns[36::18]]
```

Is there a way to get the reduced output I desire above through all 432 columns?

Comment: Updated and corrected. Thank you.

Comment: should drop 12 & 13, keep 14 (which actually is 15th column).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
col_to_keep = 5
col_to_drop = 2
period =  col_to_keep + col_to_drop

s = (np.arange(len(df.columns)) % period) < col_to_keep
df.loc[:,s]
```

Output:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   7   8   9   10  11  14
0   1  12  13  15  10  10  21   2   3  14  12
1  11   2  43   6  12  10  22   2   3  14   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compute a column index:

For the reduced example:

```
cols = [col for i, col in enumerate(df.columns) if i%7 < 5]
df_reduced = df[cols]
```

For the larger example:

```
cols = [col for i, col in enumerate(df.columns) if i%48 < 36]
df_reduced = df[cols]
```